# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/node/NodeOutputFileSystem' React App after upgrading Webpack 4 to 5

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Got this error after upgrading webpack from 4 to 5.

I saw this error on many other questions, but nothing seems to solve my issue.

This are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
    "@bootstrap-styled/color": "^1.0.9",
    "@bootstrap-styled/css-mixins": "^2.0.7",
    "@bootstrap-styled/css-utils": "^1.3.2",
    "@bootstrap-styled/navigation-bar": "^1.9.5",
    "@bootstrap-styled/provider": "^1.5.1",
    "@bootstrap-styled/v4": "^3.1.5",
    "bootstrap-styled": "^2.5.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.2",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "6.4.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "draft-js": "^0.11.7",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.1.0",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.0",
    "immer": "9.0.6",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "js-sha512": "^0.8.0",
    "kefir": "^3.8.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "6.0.0-beta",
    "react-intl": "2.8.0",
    "react-redux": "7.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.2",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "8.0.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.15",
    "showdown": "^1.9.1",
    "styled-components": "4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "7.4.0",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
    "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "6.0.2",
    "coveralls": "3.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.6.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "26.4.2",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "^6.3.3",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "ngrok": "3.1.1",
    "node-plop": "^0.26.2",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "plop": "^2.7.4",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "6.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "shelljs": "0.8.3",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "13.13.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.6.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "url-loader": "1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.60.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.1",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.3.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  }
}
```

And this is my webpack config:

```
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = options => ({
  mode: options.mode,
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign(
    {
      // Compile into js/build.js
      path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
      publicPath: '/',
    },
    options.output,
  ), // Merge with env dependent settings
  optimization: options.optimization,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // Transform all .js and .jsx files required somewhere with Babel
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: options.babelQuery,
        },
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
              noquotes: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              // Inline files smaller than 10 kB
              limit: 10 * 1024,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                enabled: false,
                // NOTE: mozjpeg is disabled as it causes errors in some Linux environments
                // Try enabling it in your environment by switching the config to:
                // enabled: true,
                // progressive: true,
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 7,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; Terser will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
      NODE_ENV: 'development',
    }),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'app'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.react.js'],
    mainFields: ['browser', 'jsnext:main', 'main'],
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

Not sure what is missing. I checked on github (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/main/lib/node) And this `NodeOutputFileSystem` does not seems to exist.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of `webpack-dev-plugin`, I had to update to `5.2.1` With that, the app is running fine again with webpack 5.

No further configuration change was needed in my case

Comment: does `webpack-dev-plugin` still exist? I don't see it in the npm registry.